# Change of CORS policy in spring boot version 2.4.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cors

Using Spring 2.3.0.RELEASE I had the following CORS confiruration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.softeq.ems.config")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class EmsJwtSecurityConfig extends BaseSecurityConfig {

    @Value("${management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins}")
    private String[] allowedOrigins;

    @Override
    protected void configureHttp(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if (allowedOrigins.length > 0) {
            http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigSource());
        }

        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigSource() {

        final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
        corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);

        Stream.of(allowedOrigins).forEach(
            origin -> corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(origin)
        );

        return request -> corsConfig;
    }
```

Variable `management.endpoints.web.cors.allowed-origins = http://localhost:4200, http://127.0.0.1:4200`

This configuration worked fine and all the cross-platform requests I needed were authorized.

But after migrating to spring-boot 2.4.0 after the release, when I tried to send a request to the host as usual, I got the classic cors policy error in chrome browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/me/balance' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status
```

Spring release notes says that the cors configuration provides a new property `allowedOriginPatterns`, but I don't understand how to use it:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x#general-web-revision

Please help me figure out what my problem is!

Answer (score 5):

Here what I would do to your code:

```
private CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigSource() {

    final CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
    corsConfig.addAllowedHeader(CorsConfiguration.ALL);
    corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(CorsConfiguration.ALL);

    Stream.of(allowedOrigins).forEach(
        //origin -> corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin(origin)
        origin -> corsConfig.addAllowedOriginPattern(origin)
    );

    return request -> corsConfig;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick for me, thanks ! Especially annoying since 
a. the change is only mentioned in the release not briefly, but nothing hinting it is a breaking change
b. The method addAllowedOrigin still exists and the beginning of the javadoc of the method says that you can still use it with wildcard * . It is explained though after that you should use addAllowedOriginPattern if setAllowCredentials(true), but that's easy to overlook

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Profile("!production")
class CorsConfig : WebMvcConfigurer {
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
        registry
            .addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOriginPatterns("http://localhost:3000")
    }
}
```